# GetUserAccessTokenAsync() always returns null in OnValidatePrincipal

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, .net-6.0

I am trying to renew the token with the below snippet. But somehow the result of `await ctx.HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();` is always `null`.. Even though i have tried to set `ctx.shouldRenew = true` before calling `await ctx.HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();` but still same result.

I am using AddOpenIdConnect to connect to IdentityServer4

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    ....
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => 
{
    ....
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents 
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = async ctx => 
        {
            var currentToken = await ctx.HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentToken))
            {
                ctx.RejectPrincipal();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate if get any help from the experts.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you could read the document :
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html#modifying-the-mvc-client

and try to set

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        .....

        options.SaveTokens = true;

        .....
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it...But still same response

Comment: Could you get the accsee token in controller as:var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

Comment: I can see the access token in controller when I use `var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();` Only after commenting `OnValidatePrincipal` on startup.cs

Comment: it was just you haven't got the accseetoken when you validate